# Multiple EditText in Dialog

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-alertdialog

Ok, HI!
For few hours Im trying to set my Dialog box to have more than one or two EditTexts, that can be editable.
EditTexts are visible on Dialog's space, but when I want to edit content of any of them and when i tap on it, this magic keyboard doesnt show up.

```
public class Statistics extends ActionBarActivity{
.
.
.
 public void buttonClick(View view) {

    Random r = new Random();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.intintmap_item_list);
    int temp = r.nextInt(6);
    for(int i = 0; i < temp; i++){
        adapter.add("data"+i);
    }
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("title");
    builder.setAdapter(adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

        }
    });
    builder
    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            Log.d("AAAAAA", "YES");

        }
    })
    .setNegativeButton("NO!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    Log.d("AAAAAA","NO");
        }
    });

    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

**intintmap_item_list.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/intintmapitemlist"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

Any1 can help? Please?

Comment: You have to set edtname.setfocusable(true); this works for me.

Comment: Doesnt work :( Cursor is visible, and it's blinking, but keyboard still doesnt show up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pasting this at the end of *buttonClick* method helped:

```
    alert.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE  | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM);
    alert.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
```